# Combine List of streams into one single stream

Tags: java, java-stream, concatenation

I have a `List<Stream<String>>` that I get by doing a series of transactions.
The list size is dynamic (Maximum 3 elements) so I can't do:

```
Stream<String> finalStream = Stream.concat(list.get(0),Stream.concat(list.get(1),list.get(2));
```

I need to concatenate the list of Streams into one single `Stream<String>`.
Is there any simple way to do this?

Comment: Take a look at `Stream#flatMap(...)`

Answer (score 6):

If you have a list of lists, or a stream of streams, or any collection of collections, you can use `flatMap` to, well, flatten them. `flatMap` applies a mapping function which must return a stream to an input and streams each element of the result of the mapping function.

In your case, you could do:

```java
var finalStream = list.stream().flatMap(x -> x);
```

`x -> x` is the identify function which returns the input unmodified. If you prefer, you can replace it with the expression `Function.identity()`.